# VS2017 Cannot debug some of the code in process dotnet.exe [21084], IntelliTrace code failed (0x80131509)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, xunit, intellitrace

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, on a .NET Core xUnit test project, and I was trying to debug some of the tests, and I encountered a popup box with the following message, how do I fix this?

> Cannot debug some of the code in process dotnet.exe [21084].  See below for status.
>
> ```
> IntelliTrace code failed (0x80131509).
> Managed (CoreCLR) code succeeded.
> ```
>
> Click OK to continue debugging the remaining code. To disable deubgging the failed type(s) of code in the future, change the corresponding setting in the project properties dialog."